Render different file types from buffer array
I am trying to display different file types in React. I am receiving the data as a buffer array from my Mongodb backend. I have been able to display images using an article I found online, and pdfs using react-pdf, but am struggling with other document types as docx. I have seen people online suggest using libraries such as react-file-viewer and react-doc-veiwer, but neither of those have any provisions on how to display files using Buffer Array data.
This is an example of how the data is received from my backend. The document file has been uploaded from my frontend.


Thank you for your reply, but I don't quite understand what you mean. If possible, could you give an example as to how the docx file can be displayed in React?
